# Clipboard listener in the background service in oreo and above devices

Tags: android, clipboard, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

I am making an instagram video downloader app for that i want to listen clipboard in the background all the time. When link is copied in the clipboard i want to show a floating window.
My question is how can i run the background service which can listen clipboard in the oreo and above devices(Oreo has background service limit).

What i tried is job Scheduler which is not a good solution.
And i don't want to start a foreground service.

And yes this is possible videoder app is doing same that i want to achieve. Below is the screenshot of it showing floating window when the link is copied in the instagram.

[Videoder Floating Window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBVSP.jpg)

Comment: Share the whole screenshots of the app. It's not possible, without foreground service on devices >=Android O.

Comment: @GensaGames  I also thought like you until i installed this app videoder..

Comment: Please add correct screenshot.